# Typewritter effect with variable in text in Python

Tags: python

I want to make typewritter effect with delay between each character.

However my problem is when I put a variable between the text it doesn't work.

```
import sys,time

message = "What's your name?\n"

def typewritter(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char != ("\n"):
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

typewritter(message)
    
name = str(input(''))

namehello = ("Hello ",name, " I'm .........")

typewritter(namehello)
```

the first part works but not the second, anyone knows how?.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `namehello` as tuple not string, keep `namehello` as string to make it work (using an f-string for example):

```
namehello = f"Hello {name} I'm ........."
```